# Installing OPUS in freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I need to install OPUS codec in my freeswitch. I have the source in my source directory. I tried to do make mod_opus from the source but it shows error. Can anyone tell me how to add mod_opus in Freeswitch?

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit the file `modules.conf` in the source tree
2. Uncomment `codecs/mod_opus`
3. Install the `libopus-dev` package
4. Recompile Freeswitch

Answer (score 2):

fs requires the version of libopus-devel to be at least 1.1 (in file configure.ac)

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([OPUS], [opus >= 1.1],[
  AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_OPUS],[true])],[
  AC_MSG_RESULT([no]); AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_OPUS],[false])])
```

**Install Howto**

(https://centos.pkgs.org/6/linuxtech/libopus-devel-1.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)

Create the repository config file /etc/yum.repos.d/linuxtech.repo:

```
[linuxtech]
name=LinuxTECH
baseurl=http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/RPM-GPG-KEY-LinuxTECH.NET
```

**Install libopus-devel rpm package:**

```
# yum install libopus-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

you can update FreeSWITCH to a new version,and it is default load of mod_opus,and you can check the conf/vars.xml , same as:

```
<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="global_codec_prefs=OPUS,G722,PCMU,PCMA,GSM"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment following lines in source and then recompile again:

```
vi freeswitch/src/mod/codecs/mod_opus/Makefile

# Comment line 889 & 890
#install: error 
#all: error
```